# Where can I find some up to date information on OpenID authentication with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

The question says it all.  I can't seem to find any recent rails tutorials or whatever to set up an OpenID authentication system.  I found [RestfulOpenIDAuthentication](http://github.com/ReinH/restful_open_id_authentication/tree/master) but it's so much older than the vanilla Restful Authentication and the docs don't even mention Rails 2 that I am pretty wary.  Does anyone have any tips?  I'd like to do what stackoverflow does and *only* have OpenID support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication) covering exactly this topic. It builds on the previous episode which discusses Restful Authentication.

Comment: I'll check it out, I just figured it wouldn't be up-to-date since it's from a year ago.

Comment: I've found Railscasts to be the best source of information. The screen casts are really high quality and Ryan Bates' knowledge is second-to-none.